# restore clonezilla image on another PC (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: 12.04, clonezilla

I use a old HP 5800 PC for installation of openfire server on Ubuntu Server 12.04. For backup, I clone whole HDD. May I know what should be procedure for restoring the image on another PC.

Or it's better I install the new PC on fresh and then only restore openfire folders.

Answer (score 0):

You have just to copy your image into the other PC (or usb stick or DVD ...). Then you start CloneZilla, choose restore from image and then choose the folder where your image is.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had tried that before. The network setting need update. I finally had fix it, but it took me more than one hour. I want know how should I properly update the network setting.